# read numbers from one file and search for them in another using awk script

Tags: awk

I have 2 files, a.txt and b.txt, both of them are composed of numbers, one per line. What I'm trying to do is to read each number from a.txt, and search for it in b.txt. Here is the `awk` script file I wrote, I can execute this `search.awk` file like this,

```
awk -f search.awk a.txt
```

but how to search for each number in b.txt?

```
#!/bin/awk -f

{
    print $1
    # how to search for $1 in b.txt?
}
```

**UPDATE**

What if there is not only **1** file to be searched, there are multiple files in a dir to be searched for each number in a.txt? I mean that, search all those files in `a_dir/*` for each number in a.txt?

Answer (score 3):

Stash lines from `a.txt` into an array and print those lines from `b.txt` that occur in the array

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]; next} $0 in a' a.txt b.txt
```

EDIT:
If there are multiple files to be searched, this version prints the match file name and line

```
awk 'NR == FNR{a[$0]; next} $0 in a{print FILENAME, $0}' a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Comment: No need for the `++`, just leave it as `a[$0];`. +1 though.

Answer (score 2):

Code example for [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1;next} $1==a[$1] && $1!=""' a.txt b.txt
```

---

```
$ cat a.txt
1
3
5
7
9
11
13

$ cat b.txt
1
4
7
10
13

$ cat c.txt
3
11

$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$1;next} $1==a[$1] && $1!=""' a.txt b.txt c.txt
1
7
13
3
11
```

Comment: Upvoted, but what if there are more than one files to be searched? Plz see my edit.

Comment: The idomatic awk solution is [almost] the one posted by @1_CR, this one has some caveats. For example it will print any blank lines from b.txt etc. which is almost certainly undesirable. Also, much like Steve Buscemis character in Fargo, it's just kinda funny-lookin' :-).

Comment: @EdMorton  You are completely right, these empty lines are ugly :) and I need unnecessary code to avoid this. Thanks.